# Loading spritesheet from bitmapdata in Phaser

Tags: javascript, bitmap, phaser-framework, sprite-sheet

I'm trying to build up an image using BitmapData and use that image as a spritesheet but I think I'm missing something.

I'm doing this in my preload...

```
oBitmapData = game.add.bitmapData(tileWidth * 2, tileHeight);
oBitmapData.ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
oBitmapData.ctx.fillRect(0,0,tileWidth, tileHeight);
oBitmapData.ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
oBitmapData.ctx.fillRect(tileWidth,0,tileWidth, tileHeight);

oSpriteSheet = game.load.spritesheet(tiles[key].name + 'Sheet', oBitmapData, tileWidth, tileHeight);
```

And then this elsewhere...

```
game.add.sprite(x, y, tiles[key].name + 'Sheet', 0, tilesGroup);
```

I get the following error when running the code

*Uncaught TypeError: url.match is not a function*

Could someone steer me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

To add a bitmapdata as a spritesheet to phaser:

```
game.cache.addSpriteSheet('key',null,bitmapdata.canvas, framewidth, frameheight);
```

Answer (score 0):

The spritesheet() function can only take a url image not a bitmapData object, see [documentation](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Loader.html#spritesheet), that is causing your error.

And creating a sprite sheet from bitmapdata is not supported by the framework AFAIK, at least according to this [forum thread](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/3840-using-bitmap-data-as-a-sprite-sheet/).